# Does Reach Router have a 'Not Exact' Setting

Tags: reactjs, routes, reach-router

I am trying to use Reach Router to create a link that is not exact.  I want users to be able to visit www.website.reset/... and land on the same page as www.website.reset/ .  I haven't found a method to make links non-exact while using Reach Router.  Is this a feature that is just missing?

Comment: @Dupocas . Are you sure this is true for Reach Router?  Are you thinking of React Router instead?

Comment: Yeap! I read react router. Deleting the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting is called a "trailing wildcard". You can see it in the documentation here:

https://reach.tech/router/api/RouteComponent

Please note that trailing wildcards will receive a 1 point penalty in the calculation of routes. [This is laid out here](https://reach.tech/router/ranking).